# HTML tables to CSV including paginated rows

Tags: php, javascript, html, pagination

This code will download the table in an html file: I got it from here: http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

```
<form action="getcsv.php" method ="post" > 
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Get CSV File"  onclick="getCSVData()">
</form>

    <script>
    function getCSVData(){
     var csv_value=$('#example1').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
     //$("#csv_text").val(csv_value);   
    }
    </script>
```

getcsv.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my-data.csv\"");
$data=stripcslashes($_REQUEST['csv_text']);

echo $data; 
?>
```

However, the table I'm extracting is paginated.
I can only get the first page. 
How can I include all of data in the table in the csv?

The paginated table looks like this:

```
<div id="paging_container8">
 <div class="page_navigation">
 </div>
   <table id="my-table">
      <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <tr style="display: none;"> // next page (paginated)
      <tr style="display: none;"> //next page (paginated)
   </table>
 <div class="page_navigation">
 </div>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You paste only the recent site table content into the csv by 
this javascript:

```
var csv_value=$('#example1').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
 //$("#csv_text").val(csv_value);
```

and php:

```
$data=stripcslashes($_REQUEST['csv_text']);
```

Your javascript only reads out the data from the recent html page so you get only them.

This is the best solution:
Change your php file to get all the data from all table sites.

Comment: the recent html page shows all the table, the paginated rows are just hidden.